# Centre of gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics

Can someone please explain to me that what exactly is center of gravity ? My book says:

> The center of gravity of a body is the point about which the algebraic sum of moments of weight of all the particles constituting the body is zero.

This definition is unclear to me. Please avoid complicated terminologies since I am a tenth grader.

Answer (score 3):

The centre-of-gravity is nothing more than kind of an "average" of gravity.

- Gravity pulls in each particle in your body a tiny bit, but on "average" if you want to consider gravity as *one* pull in your body, then it pulls in the centre-of-gravity.

Then you can either say that *gravity pulls in each of your atoms*, or you can more usefully say that *gravity pulls in your centre-of-gravity*.

The explanation you have found simply tries to explain that there is a kind of equilibrium around this centre-of-gravity.

- An astronout in space doesn't spin around wildly - gravity *doesn't* make him spin. I you pulled down in his arm, he would start to spin around, because you cause a *moment* or *torque* about his center of gravity, but if you pull in his *centre-of-gravity*, then he will not spin (only move). It's like pulling a steering wheel; you will make it turn/rotate around it's center. But if you pull at the center, then it will *not* rotate.*

So this point is kind of an "equilibrium-center" where all such torques are zero. Because if they weren't zero about this point, he *would* spin about this point. Since such an "equilibrium-point" exists, people have chosen to give it a name: *center of gravity*.

---

<sub>* Note that in this description I have assumed the centre-of-mass and the centre-of-gravity to be equal. For a very large object that significantly feels more gravitational force at points nearer to the gravitatonal source, the centre-of-gravity will be offset towards the source and will not coincide with the centre-of-mass.</sub>

Comment: ", because you cause a moment or torque about his center of mass, " should be ", because you cause a moment or torque about his center of gravity, "

Comment: @JoeFlowers Thanks, Joe, and I have made some corrections so the centre-of-mass is not mentioned, since it isn't relevant, and also added a footnote.

Answer (score 1):

Gravitational force is a vector.A rigid body contains different particles with different mass and different position so the gravitational attractive force on each particles are different.The vector sum of those gravitational vectors give a resultant vector which is a same,the gravitational force by a point particle with the same mass of the body located at the center of gravity .

Answer (score 1):

Center of gravity (cg) of an object in the most intuitive way to understand is a point where if you hang that that object from it will stay balanced suspended.

They still use this method to find the cg if small airplanes by hanging them from a small lift. 
Center of gravity of a circle is its canter, of a sphere is again its center.
It is a point that if you apply a force to the object will start to move (accelerate) without rotation.
In objects made entirely if one material cg is the same as the geometrical center but if the object is made if different materials, heavier material pulls the cg closer to it. So if you were to hang a hammer in balance you would need to hang it much closer to steel head.
In general if we divide an object into very small cubical parts each with a  small mass if m, ultimately $$ X_cg = sum (dm.x)/mass$$ where x is the distance to each one if those  small parts. It would look like you asked those small parts to vote in an ideal democracy.

Answer (score 1):

The more general term is *center of mass* and it exists even in the absence of gravity. It is a specific fixed location on a rigid body that has the following property:

*Any force applied on the body with its line of action through the center of mass is going to cause a pure translation and no rotation*.

Think of pushing a box on a frictionless surface. If you push from a corner the box is going to move and rotate at the same time. But if you push towards the center of mass the box is just going to move with no rotation.

Another consequence of this is if you suspend a body through the center of mass it will be balanced (since from above there will be no rotation).

PS. There is a related definition to the center of mass and it has to do with idealizing a solid body in motion as a single particle with "lumped" mass concentrated on the center of mass. This ideal particle carries the same momentum as the whole rigid body and it will respond to forces in the same way as the rigid body (ignoring rotations). But I think this reasoning may be too ahead of you right now.